# How do I remove the clock from the Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 desktop?

Tags: widgets, ubuntu-budgie

I just installed a Ubuntu Budgie Bionic and it comes with a clock on the Desktop. It also has one in the taskbar at the top.

How can I remove the one on the desktop?

```
cat /var/log/installer/version
ubiquity 18.04.14.1
```

After some tinkering and killing processes that looked right, the clock dissapears when I stop

```
/usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/budgie-desktop/plugins/budgie-showtime/ShowTime
```

But it reappears after I restart, so I assume that this ShowTime thingy is configured somewhere, I just can't find where.

Its about the Clock that partially overlaps with the "Tuxedo Computers" text in the bottom right.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The clock is a budgie-desktop applet.  Like other applets you can modify, add and remove applets from Budgie Settings.

Open Budgie Settings from the menu or Raven.  Look at the list of applets in your Panel (Applets tab) and click on "Desktop time & date".  You can the delete the applet.

[image]

Comment: Ah! Desktop time and Date! Thank you! I tried removing the "Clock" one, but that didn't help. Should have looked more closely.

Comment: I don't see Desktop Time & Date on mine, I went through every one. I'm on 18.10 and I still see a clock. So I tried adding one, and the option to add one wasn't there either. FWIW I installed budgie on top of an existing vanilla ubuntu
It must have moved in 18.10?

Answer (score 5):

In 18.10 it's been renamed to a more vague `ShowTime` applet.

---

I actually preferred the old name since it was very clear what it meant.

Also it'd be nice for this not to be part of the panel, since, well, it's not part of the panel. A Desktop Widget section is usually where these things are in other OS's